# Custom control canvas preventing scrolling in scrollviewer - Windows Runtime

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, custom-controls

I have a **ScrollViewer** that holds a **StackPanel** (vertical) which holds some very wide custom controls I designed. The **ScrollViewer** is there to allow the user to scroll around horizontally for the custom controls.

When I use a mouse input for the simulator I get a scrollbar and that works fine. When I use touch input for the simulator I can scroll by dragging on the custom control, but only in certain areas. If I try to drag with my touch starting on a **Canvas** element within the custom control it doesn't work. However if I drag with my touch starting outside of that canvas (in margin space, etc.) it works the way you would expect.

The canvas has some manipulation event handlers in it for various functions within the custom control. Is there any chance that these are stealing the input so that the **ScrollViewer** can't do it's job?  If that's the case is there anything I can do to make them report the input upward for the **ScrollViewer**?  Or am I investigating in the wrong place?

I can post code as requested.

**EDIT:**

Upon further investigation with some careful clicking I found something out.  My wide control has some (other) custom controls inside and a bunch of lines.  When I start my drag on a line it drags just as expected.  All the other space is filled with the second custom controls (it's very packed together).  It turns out my custom controls were stealing the input.  I had uncheck all the types of interactions on the main canvas in the second custom control and set the *Manipulation* to scale rather than system.  Set these back to the defaults fixed the issue.

Comment: If possible post code or upload the project on dropbox/skydrive.

Comment: Working with StackPanels and ScrollViewers and trying to scroll can sometimes be somewhat buggy - try replacing the stackpanel with a Grid with Rows, and see if that fixes the issue. I has fixed it when ever I had the problem with scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further investigation with some careful clicking I found something out.  My wide control has some (other) custom controls inside and a bunch of lines.  When I start my drag on a line it drags just as expected.  All the other space is filled with the second custom controls (it's very packed together).  It turns out my custom controls were stealing the input.

**Important Part:**

I had uncheck all the types of interactions on the main canvas in the second custom control and set the *Manipulation* to scale rather than system (which is probably the part that was stealing the input).  Set these back to the defaults fixed the issue.

PS: I feel dumb